# Embedded Jetty and Jax-rs xml configuration

Tags: java, spring, rest, jax-rs, embedded-jetty

Hey guys i am trying to configure and run a Restful service using Embedded-jetty and jax-rs i found this [tutorial](http://java.dzone.com/articles/going-restnoxml-embedding) and it works brilliantly however one of my requirements is to configure as much as possible through spring xml in the applicationContext.xml file.

The part i would like to do in xml is the AppConfig.java class

```
    @Configuration
public class AppConfig { 
    @Bean( destroyMethod = "shutdown" )
    public SpringBus cxf() {
        return new SpringBus();
    }

    @Bean
    public Server jaxRsServer() {
        JAXRSServerFactoryBean factory = RuntimeDelegate.getInstance().createEndpoint( jaxRsApiApplication(), JAXRSServerFactoryBean.class );
        factory.setServiceBeans( Arrays.< Object >asList( peopleRestService() ) );
        factory.setAddress( '/' + factory.getAddress() );
        factory.setProviders( Arrays.< Object >asList( jsonProvider() ) );
        return factory.create();
    }

    @Bean 
    public JaxRsApiApplication jaxRsApiApplication() {
        return new JaxRsApiApplication();
    }

    @Bean 
    public StatsRestService peopleRestService() {
        return new StatsRestService();
    }

    @Bean 
    public StatsService peopleService() {
        return new StatsService();
    }

    @Bean
    public JacksonJsonProvider jsonProvider() {
        return new JacksonJsonProvider();
    }
}
```

and where it is used

```
context.setInitParameter( "contextClass", AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.class.getName() );
context.setInitParameter( "contextConfigLocation", AppConfig.class.getName() );
```

unfortunately i can not find any decent posts online on how to do this in XML, i would greatly appreciate some help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to configure Spring via the XML then you need to move everything from the `AppConfig` class into the `${project}/src/applicationContext.xml` and reference it like this:

```
context.setInitParameter("contextConfigLocation", "classpath:applicationContext.xml");
```

And [an example](https://github.com/gcase/spring-data-rest-datatable-example/blob/master/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml) of a working `applicationContext.xml`. You should check Spring Framework's website for API reference. But you can start with this [tutorial](http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/intro-to-ioc-creating-a-spring-application.html).

Comment: Yes i realize that, i have a working applicationContext.xml that defines other beans mongodb factory rabbitmq etc, my question was that i can not find the / do not know the xml for configuring an embedded jetty server using jax-rs....
ie what do i put in the xml file that is equivalent to my AppConfig.java

Comment: For the simple beans like `peopleService` you need `<bean id="peopleService" class="StatsService"/>`. For the `jaxRsServer` bean you'll have to play a little, maybe use a factory.